# Clicking EditText causes Button onClick() functions to not work

Tags: java, android

I have an `ExpandableListView` whose children are a `RelativeLayout` of four `LinearLayout`s that contain `TextViews` which will pull answers to a question and assign that question a score from 1-4 (bad, mediocre, good, and world class respectively), and finally an `EditText` for the user to leave comments on why they rated the question that score. When the user clicks a score box, the background changes colour to highlight the selected score, and sets the other score box colours back to their default colour to show that they are no longer selected. Below is my Java to show how this works:

```
   // ChildView views
    badScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_badView);
    mediocreScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_mediocreView);
    goodScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_goodView);
    worldclassScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_wcView);
    badScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_badTextView);
    mediocreScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_mediumTextView);
    goodScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_goodTextView);
    worldClassScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_worldclassTextView);
    questionCommentEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_commentEditText);

    // TODO: TextView score subcategory setters

    badScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 1;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eca9a7"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
            questionCommentEditText.clearFocus();
        }
    });

    mediocreScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 2;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7d6a6"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
            questionCommentEditText.clearFocus();
        }
    });

    goodScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 3;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#addbad"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
            questionCommentEditText.clearFocus();
        }
    });

    worldclassScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 4;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80baeb"));
            questionCommentEditText.clearFocus();
        }
    });
```

And the layout, just in case that is relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_elv_item_score_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_badView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/badScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_badTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Bad"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_mediocreView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/mediocreScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_mediumTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Mediocre"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_goodView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/goodScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_goodTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Good"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_wcView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/worldclassScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_worldclassTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="World Class"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_commentEditText"
    android:layout_width="930dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/qwedit_elv_item_score_container"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Comments"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason, when the user presses the `EditText` and either adds text or clicks out of it, the button `onClick()` functions no longer work (i.e., they no longer change colour).

Is this due to something with focus? the javacode onClick functions are in a `CustomListViewAdapter`in order to be able to inflate the same `ExpandableListView` for as many Questions as I will have (somewhere around 200 or so).

Comment: Remove this line: android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: Hmm, that didnt seem to be it. Issue continues to be present regardless of that line being there or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem is with the focus of the View. You might need to use an OnFocusChangeListener and then check if the focus event happened when the screen was in touch mode.

Or you could try to add these lines inside each onClick(View view) method:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

This way, view will get focus and you could do something inside the onClick() method after these lines of code, after the view was again set into setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: Hmm, how would you suggest implementing the OnFocusChangeListener? I tried the simpler suggestion of adding the three lines to each `onClick()` method, but that didn't solve it

Comment: Have you tried to add these lines to your LinearLayout which holds the buttons: android:focusable="true", android:focusableInTouchMode="true" ?